# Why are the debugger memory windows not available in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

The Visual Studio Debugger has those memory windows, to inspect raw memory. In Visual Studio 2015, these still exist, since there are commands associated (ok, and the docu says so). They do not show up however.

In the menu, Debug->Windows->.... there are no Memory Windows (4 should be)
Moreover, the keyboard shortcut for the Commands Memory1 ... Memory4 replies

"the key combination ...... is bound to a command (Memory 1) which is not currently available"

I tried this in C# but also in a Win32 C++ console app. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the MSDN page on the [Memory Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx)

> The Memory window is available only if address-level debugging is enabled in the Optionsdialog box,Debugging node. The Memory window is not available for Script or SQL, which are languages that do not recognize the concept of memory.

I can confirm that if you do not have "Address-level debugging" checked the option is hidden but if you have it checked the option is shown.

[image]

(Without the option checked)
[image]

(Same debugging session, after the option was checked)
[image]

It appears that `Disassembly` and `Registers` also shows up when address mode debugging is enabled.

Comment: due to the cool quick launch ctrl-Q, I found the setting immediately, but great you added that img as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of nice debugging tools in VS2015, part of that includes memory management so perhaps the old options have been replaced.

Here is a video going through the new features: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-2015-Diagnostic-Tools

Comment: If this would be the case, then the commands would not be there anymore. Also the new tools have nothing that substitutes memory view. Also the docu still has them https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx .