# In the Visual Studio debugger, how do I print a range of bytes from memory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I need to extract a data structure from the memory of an application I am debugging that is a specific amount of bytes wide, preferably in the form of a series of hex pairs. I want to get this data from the command or immediate window in the Visual Studio Debugger. I could achieve this in windbg via the db command, but I am having trouble finding the specific command for Visual Studio. Debug.Print is insufficient, as it stops printing as soon as it encounters a null character.

I know such a command exists as I have used it before, but I can't for the life of me find it. This is what I get for not writing things down.

Comment: Have you tried using the Visual Studio Immediate Window?  It allows for you to run larger snippets of code then a Watch or a normal Debug view.  You could even create a variable in Immediate Window starting at the memory address and adding the bytes in, and then dump the contents of the variable. First set a breakpoint, then when it's hit write some code in the Immediate Window and it should work.

Comment: Visual Studio has the [Memory debug window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013400/why-are-the-debugger-memory-windows-not-available-in-vs-2015), where you can see a block of memory that updates in real time.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to find the answer to this after digging through some documentation. The command I wanted was [Debug.ListMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/list-memory-command?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Debug.ListMemory)%26rd%3Dtrue), which is aliased to the **d** command. The command to print bytes in hex pairs is specifically **db /Count:[number of bytes to print] [memory address]**.

```
>db /Count:1686 0x0000021f7102d4d0
0x0000021F7102D4D0  48 72 2f 50 73 36 68 75 4e 6c 59 44 44 56 33 33  
0x0000021F7102D4E0  38 78 37 4f 55 65 6c 62 6c 6f 51 78 77 66 4e 68  
0x0000021F7102D4F0  35 73 4e 35 42 68 4d 67 54 7a 6e 35 6d 36 52 41
...
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer later.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `p` is a pointer to the array of bytes you can enter watch like this:

```
(p + start_pos),[items_count]
```

Comment: That doesn't produce a very readable display.  What's wrong with using the memory window?  You can even copy and paste from it.

Comment: @PaulSanders Output seems fine to me. Also this method is universal and can be used to display complex items.

Comment: Ah yes, but the OP asked for, in effect, a hex dump.  With your method, for some arbitrarily chosen bit of memory, I get: `(unsigned char *) &msg,16 0x0019fc6c "n\nô\0\x13\x1\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"`

Comment: @PaulSanders You can expand array view. It will list individual values. This is definitely far from a hex dump, but if someone wants just a hex dump then memory windows would be the obvious choose.